# inverse to split in jsx

Tags: javascript, split, jsx

In jsx we have the split function. Given an array like ['001','002','003'] is there a function that we could call "the inverse of split" that could convert arrays like  ['001','002','003']  to a string like

```
  '001;002;003'
```

that unified the elements of that array using a separator like  ;?

Comment: You mean `join(';')`. This is an [JS array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), not something specific to JSX.

Answer (score 1):

Is this:

```
['001','002','003'].join(';');
```

what you need?